# ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

Tags: android

I have a question.

Android 8.0 introduces a new Context.startForegroundService () method that creates a new service in the foreground.

But I update target version to Android 12 , App is crushed.
Error is ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.

I'm implementing app like spotify or apple music.

Shouldn't startForegroundService() be used in applications with the target version set to Android 12?
And Should I use only startForeground() ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Behavior Changes Again.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

You should start the service when the app is in front.

Answer (score 4):

From Android 12 onwards, apps are no longer allowed to start a foreground service while the app is in background. In order to start a foreground service while the app is in background, you have to do 3 things

1. Declare the service type of `mediaPlayback`, `mediaProjection`, or `phoneCall` in manifest (only these types are allowed to show immediate notifications and start service).
2. You have to declare `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_PHONE_CALL` or `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION` or `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK` permission in manifest (compileSDKVersion 34)
3. Inside service's `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()`, pass `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_PHONE_CALL` or `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION` or `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK` as 3rd parameter of `startForeGround()`

There might be additional runtime requirements. For more information on service types, check https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fg-service-types#phoneCall

Comment: i think for # 3 only need to do that if your service has different use cases ..but otherwise it will default to using whats in #1 ... right ?

Comment: You need to pass 3rd parameter of `startForeground()` according to the service type defined in manifest