# Playing media item with app in the background triggers ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm currently using the Media3 library to play content and everything works perfectly when the mediaController.play() is triggered when the app is in the foreground.

**The use case: **
Tracks from playlists have no mediaUri (the link to the actual .mp3). We are required to fetch a playlist (let's say with 30 tracks), and then fetch the url for each given track. The problem is that the url we receive is only valid for 2 minutes.

**The solution we are using now is: **
We have a worker class that observes (via flow) the player state, and when STATE_ENDED, it fetches the url of the next track and plays it (mediaController.setMediaItems > prepare() > play())

**The problem:**
When the app is in the background (screen off) and the track ends, the new track starts playing but we get a ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException error (no crash), and the media notification image doesn't update.

`Failed to start foreground android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service 'APPNAME.media.MediaService`

Am I missing something obvious or is Media3 still janky to handle these cases where we need to fetch the mediaUri on demand

The MediaLibraryService is properly set with the given permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application>...
     <service
          android:name=".MediaService"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="false"
          android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback|dataSync">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService" />
              <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
</application>
```

This is the function that gets called to play content:

```
    private fun playAppPlaylist(startAtIndex: Int = 0) {
        val browser = this.browser ?: return
        val items = browser.getChildren(
            Catalog.AppPlaylist.path, 0, Int.MAX_VALUE, null
        )
        items.addListener({
            val result = items.get()
            val children = result.value!!

            browser.setMediaItems(children)
            browser.prepare()
            if (startAtIndex != 0) browser.seekTo(startAtIndex, 0)
            else browser.seekToDefaultPosition()
            browser.play()
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
    }
```

Seems like calling `browser.play()` when the app is not in the foreground triggers a notificationChange which is causing the error.
I've tried thinking of solutions where I don't use .play() but `controller.replaceMediaItem()` but the media doesn't start playing since it has been paused when became `Player.STATE_ENDED`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 12, it has become harder to start foreground services whenever your app is in the background.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77359307/13021452), you may need to pass in the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK` as the 3rd parameter of your `startForeGround(..)` call (which is not shown in the code you provided.

Looking further into the code you did provide, I suspect that having the `dataSync` flag as part of your `foregroundServiceType` declaration might be making Android think that you should not be dong anything from the background, but you would have to try that out yourself!